# Can you identify a time travel story in which every attendant of the passion of Jesus Christ turns out to be a time traveller?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I've read twice now about a short story in which time travel is a vacation thing, with destinations offered at the travelers's choice. The protagonist realizes that he could attend the passion of Jesus Christ. While there he finds that all the other attendants are time travellers as well.

I've first saw this mentioned about 25 years ago in an edition of GEO magazine (can't remember which one) in an editorial about ... I think it was physics, time travel, but could be something else entirely. The second time I saw it referenced in the novel "Jesus Video" by Andreas Eschbach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_Video

Comment: [Let's Go to Golgotha!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Go_to_Golgotha!)

Comment: [Up the Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_the_Line)

Comment: You might also like these tropes; "[Adventures in the Bible](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AdventuresInTheBible)" and "[Field Trip to the Past](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FieldTripToThePast)".

Comment: @starpilotsix - And while that's true, the bit where they go to the Sermon on the Mount / The crucifixion is quite a small part of a larger novella and easily mistaken for a short story given the way the chapters are structured. My money is on "Let's Go to Golgotha!" though.

Comment: @Valorum thanks for the very interesting links - I've checked them all. Golgotha sounds close, yet the mentions, if I remember, said that the traveller went solo and realized what was up during the passion, not (as is Let's Go ...) when Pilates puts Jesus before the crowd or (as in Up the Line) with organized travel groups to Golgatha.

Comment: @HumanInDisguise - Hmm. Can you post the actual references?

Comment: I've voted to close as too broad. There are a host of stories that match the description and it doesn't look like the OP is able to offer any additional info to work with.

Comment: This actually does sound very familiar, and by none of Valorum's suggestions. Did it possibly appear in an edition of the anthology Year's Best New SF, edited by Gardiner Dozois?

Comment: @Valorum I think voting to close is the wrong thing to do.  Maybe a web search didn't turn up the answer, but maybe someone who knows the story will see this question and answer it in the future.  The web isn't the repository of *all* human knowledge, yet...

Comment: @LAK - The problem here is that the OP doesn't ***know what the right answer is***. He was presumably expecting his description to be unique (*"man goes to visit blue aliens on alien world called Pandora"*) rather than generic (*"Aliens invade Earth"*).

Comment: It's probably Golgotha.I usually is. I'd post that as,an answer and delete it later if the OP changes the question.

Comment: @Valorum please post your first comment as an answer so I can accept it and credit you. Else I'd vote myself for this question to be too broad, considering the fact that both my sources are describing something they've read or heared about quite some time ago, making it likely they're misremembering it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely to be [Let's Go to Golgotha!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Go_to_Golgotha!) by Gary Kilworth.

The protagonist travels to Golgotha (to witness the crucifixion of Jesus) only to then realise that the entire crowd is composed of fellow time travelers.

> "Harry," choked Simon, as quickly as his emotion would allow, "Harry, we've got to get him down."
>   Harry's stunned mind took time to register the fact that Simon was with them once more. He did not take his eyes from the man on the centre cross.
>   Licking his lips, he replied helplessly, "Can't do it, Simon. It's got to happen, you know. This is the way it is, but, my God, I wish we had never come. He looked at me, you know. I'll never forget his eyes as long as I live. They were so ..." he paused to find a word,"... so deep."
>   **Simon was frantic. "Harry, Harry. Look at the crowd! Look around you! There are no Jews here. No natives. The only ones here are us. The holiday-makers. Do you realize the enormity of what we've done? The whole guilt of mankind rests on our shoulders."**
>   He was sobbing violently now. "We've crucified the Son of God, and we're going to do it next tour, and the next and the next..."
>   "For ever and ever, time without end, amen," finished Harry, humbly.